# fastest way to offset indexes of a Typed Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, buffer, arraybuffer

I'm working with very large arrays (millions of data points) and would like to know the fastest way to offset a chunk of the array.  I'm currently doing this in a for loop.

For example, let's say I have a typed array:

`[5, 6, 7, 10, 1, 14, 4, 5, 1, 10, 25, 20, 21, 5, 9, 7, 7, 3, 4]`

I have to keep this array in memory as my "original".

Now I want to remove the chunk from index 5 up to index 8 (which would be `[14, 4, 5]`),

So I should be left with:

`[5, 6, 7, 10, 1, 1, 10, 25, 20, 21, 5, 9, 7, 7, 3, 4]`

Then I want to remove the chunk from the result's index 3 up to index 5 (which would be (`[10, 1]`)

So I should be left with:

`[5, 6, 7, 1, 10, 25, 20, 21, 5, 9, 7, 7, 3, 4]`

For each of these edits, I've been keeping track of the start and end indexes, and my edits array would look something like this:

```
edits = [
    {
      start: 5
      end: 8
    },
    {
      start: 3
      end: 5
    }
]
```

So now let's say I want to "go back" one edit.  I simulate the changing of indexes of the original array without making new array or changing the original.

Now at this point assume I have a mapping of where index values are located if it changed (an offset which is equivalent to the length of the chunk removed).

Example – if I removed from index 5 up to 8, I would keep track that everything after index 5 in the original array would now be 3 (8-5) indexes behind.  Everything before index 5 would remain in the same position.

Can I use `.set` or `.subarray` on a copy of the original?  Would this be faster than looping through the original array and setting values on the new array based on a certain offset index in the original array?

Memory usage is also a concern so I would like to try to do it using the existing buffer of the typed array if possible.

Comment: Ever heard of `.slice()`?

Comment: Technically I could do it with multiple `.slice()` calls since I would have to slice before the index start, and after the index end.   Then I would concat the two arrays.  Since slice returns a new array, I wasn't sure if this would be the most efficient.